# Pandas reading a specific line in python with a csv file

Tags: python, pandas

I want to read a specific line in a csv file in pandas on python.Here on this image I want to read the 19010101 date [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBuTQ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the column you want to use

```
df=read_csv(yourcsv.csv)
dates = df['DATE'].values.tolist()
print(dates[0])
```

Bunch of ways to do this, just depends on your requirements. 
[Iloc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) function might be of use to you too.

Comment: Glad to help! Good luck on your project

Comment: Is it possible to specify which line you want to read? eg I want to read 3 line from behind (index = -3)